# Using a static library (.a) in Visual Studio Express 2013

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to call a function found in a static lib (xxx.a) from a Visual Studio Express 2013 project. 
(The static lib is the output of a C project, compiled in IAR workspace).

In my Visual Studio project I added the library folder location to the VC++ directories (both under include directories & library directories), and under linker->Input->additional dependencies I added the library itslef (xxx.a ).

When I compile the project, I get a linker error:

> C3861 (identifier not found).

What am I missing? I am newbie as it comes to library usage, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2013 cannot read .a format static libraries. Even if it could, the static library is surely not linked against the same version of the C library as you're trying to build against.

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by: " the static library is surely not linked against the same version of the C library as you're trying to build against" ?

Comment: Radically different compilers use different C standard libraries. This is a windows specific gotcha. Somehow MS does not understand this is a bad idea.